# At what cosmological redshift $z$, does the recession speed equal the speed of light? How is it calculated?

Tags: expansion, redshift, hubble-constant

At what cosmological redshift $z$, does the recession speed equal the speed of light?

What equations are used to calculate this number (since at large redshifts, $z=v/c$ won't apply)?

[The interested reader may refer to answers on [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/518543/at-what-cosmological-redshift-z-does-recession-speed-equal-the-speed-of-light).]

Comment: @uhoh Thanks for the link. However, the equations for relativistic redshift do not apply to cosmological redshift, where $v \ge c$ is quite well known and commonly observed.

Comment: Oops, I missed that, thanks!

Comment: Duplicate at Physics SE and it has an answer there https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/518543/at-what-cosmological-redshift-z-does-recession-speed-equal-the-speed-of-light

Comment: @Alchimista The answer clearly doesn't show how is the number $z \sim 1.5$ arrived at.

Comment: It is in there. You can't further simplify things. You have equation and various plots depending on parameters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP asked the [same question on Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/518543/at-what-cosmological-redshift-z-does-recession-speed-equal-the-speed-of-light) where it has been answered. Cross-posting the same question on different SE sites is discouraged.

Comment: @ChappoSaysReinstateMonica Even when one of the questions doesn't get an answer in 60 hours?

Comment: Ritesh, please take the [Tour] of our site and read the guidance available on the [Help] page. If you have multiple questions, you should ask them separately: too broad a post is grounds for closure. In any case, if you're unsatisfied with the answer on [Physics.se], why did you accept it?

Comment: @ChappoSaysReinstateMonica I never said I was unsatisfied with the answer on Physics SE. I asked this question here first and when it didn't an answer in 2 days I asked it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Friedmann Equation, distance as a function of redshift is:

$$d(z)=\frac{c}{H_0}\int_0^z \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\Omega_{R_0}(1+x)^4+\Omega_{M_0}(1+x)^3+\Omega_{K_0}(1+x)^2+\Omega_{\Lambda_0}}}$$

The Hubble-Lemaître Law:

$$v=H_0 \cdot d$$

We want $\boxed{v=c}$ The distance that fulfils this condition is known as Hubble Distance, (or Hubble Radius, or Hubble Length):

$$d_H=\frac{c}{H_0}$$

Combining both, we obtain the condition:

$$\int_0^z \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\Omega_{R_0}(1+x)^4+\Omega_{M_0}(1+x)^3+\Omega_{K_0}(1+x)^2+\Omega_{\Lambda_0}}}=1$$

For $\Omega_{R_0}\approx 0 \quad \Omega_{K_0}\approx 0 \quad \Omega_{M_0}\approx 0.31 \quad \Omega_{\Lambda_0}\approx 0.69$

The condition is:

$$\int_0^z \frac{dx}{\sqrt{0.31(1+x)^3+0.69}}=1$$

Searching by trial and error, we find that the value of redshift that fulfils the condition is: $$z=1.474 \approx 1.5$$

I hope I am not breaking any rules by repeating here the solution I wrote on [Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/518543/at-what-cosmological-redshift-z-does-the-recession-speed-equal-the-speed-of-l)
I did it because the creator of the thread asked me to do it, there.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you! I am sure no rules are broken by trying to help the community :)